# How would I return true if an employee is above or below a certain temperature?

Tags: java, return, boolean

I need to make the program return true (meaning the employee is sick) if their temperature is outside of the range of 32-38, and they have a new cough OR loss of smell. Otherwise, employee is not sick (needs to return false.)

Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean returntowork(float temperature, boolean newCough, boolean lossOfSmell) {
    if (temperature >= 38 && newCough || lossOfSmell);
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Looks OK to me at first glance. Do we want the method to return true if `lossofSmell` is true, even if `temperature` is less than 38? Could you provide a set of test data, with expected and actual results?

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut Hello, so what I need is for the method to return true if the temperature is above 38 OR lower than 32, and either loss of smell is true OR new cough is true.
Thanks :)

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Is it _(temperature is outside of the range of 32-38), and (they have a new cough OR loss of smell)_  --*OR*-- _(temperature is outside of the range of 32-38, and they have a new cough) OR (loss of smell)_? Based on current thinking, loss of smell outranks temperature as diagnostic.

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry. I'm new to this.
So i'm trying to make it return true (meaning they're sick) if the person has a temperature which is below 32 or higher than 38. As well as this, they have either a new cough or a loss of smell. I think that's the best I can word it. Sorry again I am new to this.

Comment: I recommend you carefully think through the possibilities.  If they have a temp of 40, but no new cough or loss of smell, are they sick?

Comment: @JimGarrison for the purpose of what I'm doing, if they have a temp which is outside the range, but no new cough or loss of smell, they are not sick

Comment: Then it's `boolean sick = ((temp < 32 || temp >38) && (newCough || lossOfSmell))` -- that is a boolean expression which you can return directly.  And the parentheses are required because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`

Comment: @JimGarrison Wow, thankyou so much! that worked a charm, thankyou kindly my man!

Answer (score 3):

You're very close. Do this.

```
return ((temperature >= 38 && newCough) || lossOfSmell);
```

The expression is a boolean, so you can just return it, instead of using `if`.

**Edit**: You can write  any logical expression you need. For example, you might do this:

```
return ( (temperature >= 38 && newCough) ||
         temperature <= 32 ||
         lossOfSmell
       );
```

If you wanted to reject too-cold temperatures, too-high temperatures with a cough, or loss of smell.

If you wanted to reject too-cold temperatures only if they came with  a cough, you could do this.

```
return ( (temperature >= 38 && newCough) ||
         (temperature <= 32 && newCough) ||
         lossOfSmell
       );
```

The point here is to make the code for your clinical indicators *really easy to read.* In the real world you might need a physician to inspect your code; you want her to have a chance at understanding it.

And, pro tip, always use parentheses to group together your `&&` and `||` operators. Don't try to remember their operator precedence or depend on it.

Comment: (Though the outer parens don't really add much in this case.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! just a quick question, how would I make it so that if the temperature is greater than 38 OR lower than 32 it should return false? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Of course you're right about the outer parens. I included them to help teach the questioner an unambiguous and clear coding style for his logical expressions. The only thing that counts here is writing the code so it's easy to reason about it. In the 21st century we can trust our C++ compilers to optimize this kind of thing.

Comment: @SmellyAlien please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use `!` as a NOT operator in boolean operations, then wrap your logic in brackets, meaning that your operation will only evaluate to `true` if the whole operation evaluates to `false`. It's essentially the same as writing `(1 == 2) != true`

You can therefore rewrite your method like so (this also avoids the `if true {return true}` antipattern)

```java
return !(newCough || lossofSmell || temperature < 32 || temperature >= 38)
```

To briefly explain, each variable is evaluated separately using the OR operator, so if any of them evaluate to `true`, then the whole expression evaluates to `false`, thanks to the `!` NOT operator at the start.

For example, say that `newCough = true`, `lossofSmell = false` and `temperature = 35`. The expression becomes:

```java
return !(true || false || false || false)
```

which simplifies to:

```java
return !true
```

and finally evaluates to `false`.